# Execute . python script from Angular JS using Flask

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I am trying to execute a python script from `flask`. I understand I need to run it on a server. I am creating this for chrome extension, so I am wondering if that's even possible to run a server everytime we need it. Furthermore, this is my code to send the request:

```
var url = './app.py';

$http.get(
url,
{
    params: {'id': "eminem"}
})
.success(function (data) {
    console.log("data");
})
.error(function (error) {
    console.log("error");
});
```

and the python code would be:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request, redirect, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def getData():
    return "db"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? The error I am getting is that the server cannot locate the file.

Comment: What do you mean, what you "might be doing wrong"? You've said what you're doing wrong, you need to run your app somewhere.

Comment: The error that I get is that the server cannot find the file or 404 error. I am just wondering if I can find an example where I can see how to call/execute a python file from an angularjs controller. @DanielRoseman

Comment: This sound like you are still missing the basic understanding of how web applications work. Simply said: you can't run a local Python script from Java Script in the browser. Call the script on the flask server via GET or POST.

Comment: @KlausD. I understand that and I am trying to implement Flask to call the method. However, it is not able to get the python file for some reason giving me a 404 error. I don't understand where the 404 error is coming from.

Comment: Your URL is wrong. It should not start with `.`.

Comment: @KlausD. I have tried that but it still gives me the same error. Is there any other restful api that I can use to call python function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Flask server you are declaring the method route as `/data` so you should be able to call it by `localhost:5000/data` (I am assuming that you are running the server in your computer with the default Flask port).

For doing that you should change your first line in your JS code like:

`var url = 'localhost:5000/data';`

Remember that you are requesting an url not a python file, it works different in php for example.